# Can I store my .flv files on a file system and have the play in my web page?

Tags: flv

When my .flv and .swf files are referenced through an http:// address they work fine but when I reference them via UNC path, they don't work. Any idea if it's possible to for it to work?

This works:

```
<object width="640" height="360">
<param name="movie" value="/flash/FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
<param name="salign" value="lt" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="scale" value="noscale" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=/flash/clearSkin_3&streamName=/flash/Ch1_Trial&autoPlay=false&autoRewind=false" />
<embed src="/flash/FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" flashvars="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=/flash/clearSkin_3&streamName=/flash/Ch1_Trial&autoPlay=false&autoRewind=false" 
    quality="high" scale="noscale" width="640" height="360" name="FLVPlayer" salign="LT" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

This does not work:

```
<object width="640" height="360">
<param name="movie" value="/flash/FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
<param name="salign" value="lt" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="scale" value="noscale" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=/flash/clearSkin_3&streamName=\\flashfileserver\flash\Ch1_Trial&autoPlay=false&autoRewind=false" />
<embed src="/flash/FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" flashvars="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=/flash/clearSkin_3&streamName=\\flashfileserver\flash\Ch1_Trial&autoPlay=false&autoRewind=false" 
    quality="high" scale="noscale" width="640" height="360" name="FLVPlayer" salign="LT" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your HTML is not showing up. Highlight it and press the little button with the 101010 to indent it four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to same origin policy.  Resources can only be loaded from the same server that served the script/plugin/etc.  Otherwise, whats to stop the script/plugin/etc from opening a file on your local system and then send the content to a third party.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: So is it something that can be configured in the browser?

Comment: Given that it is a significant security risk, I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks Craig. But this is only if the path is not an "http://" request right? You can point to .flv files located on a separate web server.